# Python: PyOpenGL AttributeError: ("'NumberHandler' object has no attribute 'arrayByteCount'", <function asArrayTypeSize.<locals>.asArraySize at )Error

Tags: python

On python, I am currently programming Project M
But I get, 
AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\arrays\arrayhelpers.py", line 115, in asArraySize
    byteSize = handler.arrayByteCount( result )
AttributeError: ("'NumberHandler' object has no attribute 'arrayByteCount'", .asArraySize at 0x0000025931F41E58>)
Help!

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace ?